# Ruby Hash Whitelist Filter

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I am trying to figure out how I can filter out key and value pairs from one filter into another

For example I want to take this hash

```
x = { "one" => "one", "two" => "two", "three" => "three"}

y = x.some_function

y == { "one" => "one", "two" => "two"}
```

Thanks for your help

EDIT: should probably mention that in this example, I want it to behave as a whitelist filter. That is, I know what I want, not what I don't want.

Comment: sounds like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430343/ruby-easiest-way-to-filter-hash-keys/#answer-30551883

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby: Easiest Way to Filter Hash Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430343/ruby-easiest-way-to-filter-hash-keys)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Maybe this it what you want.

```
wanted_keys = %w[one two]
x = { "one" => "one", "two" => "two", "three" => "three"}
x.select { |key,_| wanted_keys.include? key }
```

The Enumerable mixin which is included in e.g. Array and Hash provides a lot of useful methods like select/reject/each/etc.. I suggest that you take a look at the documentation for it with ri Enumerable.

Comment: but the select method returns an array. In this case I need a hash

Comment: For 1.8.7 use `reject` and negate the condition

Answer (score 108):

Rails' ActiveSupport library also gives you slice and except for dealing with the hash on a key level:

```
y = x.slice("one", "two") # => { "one" => "one", "two" => "two" }
y = x.except("three")     # => { "one" => "one", "two" => "two" }
x.slice!("one", "two")    # x is now { "one" => "one", "two" => "two" }
```

These are quite nice, and I use them all the time.

Comment: And if x is an ActiveRecord::Base subclass, you can do `y = x.attributes.slice *%w(one two three)`.

Comment: If you're familiar with [`_.pick` in Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#pick), this is the same idea.  (I came here looking for that!)

Comment: And `ActiveSupport` is pretty lightweight, it's used by many non-Rails gems.

Comment: Booyah! Exactly what I needed

Comment: If you have an array of attributes like the `wanted_keys` in sris's answer, you could do `y = x.slice(*wanted_keys)`

Comment: careful with `slice` if you care about the hash's ordering. It will always order the output by the args passed into it.

Answer (score 49):

You can just use the built in Hash function reject.

```
x = { "one" => "one", "two" => "two", "three" => "three"}
y = x.reject {|key,value| key == "three" }
y == { "one" => "one", "two" => "two"}
```

You can put whatever logic you want into the reject, and if the block returns true it will skip that key,value in the new hash.

Comment: 5 seconds behind on the typing... I knew I should have posted before testing to make sure I didn't make a typo.

Comment: You can use `reject!` rather than setting another variable

Comment: @Radar Destructive modifiers can cause problems, if for instance the hash is being passed in as an argument to a method and the caller does not expect the hash to be modified by that method. Best to be in the habit of doing non-destructive updates, and only use destructive operators when necessary.

Comment: This is good however I may not know the other hash keys. I only know the ones that I want

Comment: Downvote because this is a blacklist filter, but the OP wants a whitelist.

Answer (score 8):

Improving a bit @scottd answer, if you are using rails and have a list of what you need, you can expand the list as parameters from slice. For example

```
hash = { "one" => "one", "two" => "two", "three" => "three"}
keys_whitelist = %W(one two)
hash.slice(*keys_whitelist)
```

And without rails, for any ruby version, you can do the following:

```
hash = { "one" => "one", "two" => "two", "three" => "three"}
keys_whitelist = %W(one two)
Hash[hash.find_all{|k,v| keys_whitelist.include?(k)}]
```

Comment: Note you don't necessarily need to be using *Rails*, you can just load Active Support. Add `active_support` to your Gemfile and `require "active_support/core_ext/hash/slice"`.

Comment: `find_all` is an alias for `select` so this is basically the same as the first two answers :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
y = x.reject {|k,v| k == "three"}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using a combination of everyone's answers I have come up with this solution:

```
 wanted_keys = %w[one two]
 x = { "one" => "one", "two" => "two", "three" => "three"}
 x.reject { |key,_| !wanted_keys.include? key }
 =>{ "one" => "one", "two" => "two"}
```

Thanks for your help guys!

EDIT:

The above works in 1.8.7+

The following works in 1.9+ :

x.select { |key,_| wanted_keys.include? key }

Comment: Why the double negative? `x.select { |key,_| wanted_keys.include? key }`? This returns a hash for me

Comment: It depends on the ruby version you are using. This works in 1.9+ but not in 1.8.7. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Downvote for accepting your own copy of @sris's answer! Your comment on that answer is sufficient to point out the difference.

Comment: @RobinGower I selected this answer 5 years ago and at the time, this was the right answer. When I made the comment 1.8.7 was still in wide use and this still was the correct answer. I can change it now but the down vote is not warranted.

Comment: Ah - I see, that comment came years later. Sorry, my vote is locked so I can't un-downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a lambda to filter. This will both allow you to write complex filtering logic & make it easy to test it. The fact that the filtering logic is extracted will allow to reuse it in other contexts.

ex:

```
x = { "one" => "one", "two" => "two", "three" => "three"}

matcher = ->(key,value) { 
  # FILTERING LOGIC HERE 
   !key[/three/]
}

x.select(&matcher) == { "one" => "one", "two" => "two"}
```