# Paperclip model validation error message appears two times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have upload funtionality in rails, am using rails paper clip. I have defined my model validation like this to check image type.

`validates_attachment :company_logo, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }`

If i upload some other file extensions, its showing two times this message. I want only one message `"Company logo content type is invalid"`

```
Company logo content type is invalid
Company logo is invalid
```

Please tell me solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933579/ruby-on-rails-4-duplicate-paperclip-validation-messages

Comment: sorry 4 late reply. It works thanks:-)