# Why can't I make a new hash from selected keys in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

This has been bugging me for a while.  It's not a difficult thing, but I don't know why there's no easy way to do it already, and I bet there is and I don't see it.

I just want to take a hash, like this:

```
cars = {:bob => 'Pontiac', :fred => 'Chrysler', 
        :lisa => 'Cadillac', :mary => 'Jaguar'}
```

and do something like

```
cars[:bob, :lisa]
```

and get

```
{:bob => 'Pontiac', :lisa => 'Cadillac'}
```

I did this, which works fine:

```
class Hash
  def pick(*keys)
    Hash[select { |k, v| keys.include?(k) }]
  end
end

ruby-1.8.7-p249 :008 > cars.pick(:bob, :lisa)
=> {:bob=>"Pontiac", :lisa=>"Cadillac"}
```

There's obviously a zillion easy ways to do this, but I'm wondering if there's something built in I've missed, or a good an un-obvious reason it's not a standard and normal thing?  Without it, I wind up using something like:

```
chosen_cars = {:bob => cars[:bob], :lisa => cars[:lisa]}
```

which isn't the end of the world, but it's not very pretty.  It seems like this should be part of the regular vocabulary.  What am I missing here?

(related questions, include this: [Ruby Hash Whitelist Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711863/ruby-hash-filter))
(this blog post has precisely the same result as me, but again, why isn't this built in? http://matthewbass.com/2008/06/26/picking-values-from-ruby-hashes/ )

update:

I'm using Rails, which has ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Hash::Slice, which works exactly as I want it to, so problem solved, but still...  maybe someone else will find their answer here :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be built-in and I don't think this is the right place to ask *why*.

Comment: I thought about deleting the question once I found ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Hash::Slice, but I figure Stack Overflow is a resource for finding answers, and I would have found it faster if this question had already been here.

Comment: I guess your question is valid and this is just a technicality, but you'd better ask *how* to do something, not *why* something is not available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to help others, some years after the fact:

Slice works nicely to do what I wanted.

```
> cars.slice(:bob, :lisa)
=> {:bob=>"Pontiac", :lisa=>"Cadillac"}
```

Comment: `Hash#slice` is a recent addition to `Hash`, used to be only available as part of ActiveSupport in Rails but became part of the Ruby core in 2.5.0.

Comment: Yup.  I figure anyone having this problem now should see the latest answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've always thought that was a weird omission as well, but there really is no simple, standard method for that.

Your example above might be unnecessarily slow because it iterates over all the hash entries whether we need them or not, and then repeatedly searches through the keys parameter array. This code should be a bit faster (assuming that would ever matter -- and I haven't tried to benchmark it).

```
class Hash
  def pick(*keys)
    values = values_at(*keys)
    Hash[keys.zip(values)]
  end
end
```

Comment: my instinct is that since your solution looks up by value instead of key, it would probably benchmark the same or slower, but at least for most applications, I'm pretty sure it won't make any material difference.

Comment: `Hash[keys.zip(values)]` is probably a bit faster with the same result

Comment: @stephan-com, values_at looks up a value for each key, and returns and array of values in the same order. There are no lookups being done by value.

Comment: @victor-moroz, I had not known that a single array argument could be passed to Hash.[], and it would seem likely that's faster than passing the array as arguments. I ran a benchmark, however, and found that passing as arguments is more than twice as fast under ruby 1.8.7-p302.  `p=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; Benchmark.measure{ 100000.times{ Hash[p] } }` gives ...@real=0.762746095657349, @utime=0.72..., and the same test using `Hash[*p]` gives ,,,@real=0.325729131698608, @utime=0.279999999999999.... I'm not at all sure what would account for that large difference, however.

Comment: Curious about the big performance discrepancy, I browsed to http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_8_7_330/Hash/%5B%5D/class, and clicked the Show Source link.  Apparently, when *array is passed, Ruby converts this to a C array & argc, then Hash.[] simply iterates the pairs, and sets each k/v. When a single array argument is passed, however, Hash[] must first try coercing it to a Hash, then try coercing it to an Array, and then iterate/extract the elements (presumably just like Ruby otherwise does prior to invocation), and then iterates & inserts. The type checking/coercion looks like the performance hit.

Comment: @SteveJorgensen There is a difference between `Hash[[1,2,3,4,5...]]` and `Hash[[[1,2], [3,4], ...]]`. `Hash[keys.zip(values)]` is the latter, it's not slower than `*p` (may be a little bit). The former one just doesn't work by the way.

Comment: @victor-moroz - I stand doubly corrected. I never knew about the `Hash[[[1,2], [3,4], ...]]` form, I just knew that `Hash[[1,2], [3,4], ...]` did not work (which means my example above is just plain wrong as you say). What I meant to say for my example was `Hash[*keys.zip(values).flatten(1)]`, in which case, #flatten certainly adds a performance hit. When I benchmark that, it takes about twice as long as `Hash[keys.zip(values)]` as one might expect.

Answer (score 1):

`select` deserves at least to be mentioned:

```
cars = {:bob => 'Pontiac', :fred => 'Chrysler', 
        :lisa => 'Cadillac', :mary => 'Jaguar'}
people = [:bob, :lisa]

p cars.select{|k, _| people.include?(k)}
#=> {:bob=>"Pontiac", :lisa=>"Cadillac"}
```

Comment: only works in ruby 1.9. ruby 1.8 will return an array http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-select

Comment: Just so it's noted, you can get the same effect from select in 1.8 by surrounding the select call with Hash[], i.e., Hash[somehash.select{|k,v| /*some select criteria*/}]

Answer (score 0):

Ruby makes it possible to add that feature without much pain:

```
class Hash
  alias old_accessor :[]

  def [](*key)
    key.is_a?(Array) ? self.dup.delete_if{|k, v| !key.include? k} : old_accessor(key)
  end
end
```

I hope this helps. I know it's not a built-in feature.

Comment: Any ideas on the pros/cons of using self.dup.delete_if over self.select?

Answer (score 0):

```
{ height: '178cm', weight: '181lbs', salary: '$2/hour' }.select { |k,v| [:height, :weight].include?(k)  }
```