# how to call a active record named scope with a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm sure I'm miss understanding the use of call but I thought I could do something like this.

```
@case_studies = CaseStudy.call("some_named_scope")
```

Where `"some_named_scope"` is also a named scope in `CaseStudy`. The reason why I need to use call is because I have named scopes that are the same names of the actions in the controller so I'm hopping to do something like this.

```
@case_studies = CaseStudy.call(params[:action])
```

**EDIT**

Forgive me, I just realized I was thinking about the send method, some how the word call got stuck in my head. But `@case_studies = CaseStudy.send(params[:action])` works as I thought it would.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `some_named_scope` is a **named_scope** of the `CaseStudy` model, you can use `send` to call the method corresponding to `params[:action]` value. But this is obviously heavily exploitable.

So, security aside, you could get going with:

```
@case_studies = CaseStudy.send(params[:action])
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I did upvoted your answer since you have answered first. I got some time to really understand what he was asking. =)

Comment: I appreciate, and yes it is a confusing question. What made me understand was the term "named scope" :-)

Comment: when you say this is obviously heavily exploitable could you point me in some direction of a better way of doing something like that?

Comment: What comes to mind is that you could at least perform a check that ensures that the `params[:action]` is within some expected values. Something like `if %w(approved pending unassigned).include?(params[:action]); ...; end`.

Comment: @DigitalCake Pulling this string in from params (i.e. the user or a bot) means they can put essentially whatever they want in there. The best way to go about this is whitelisting your expected values so that nothing out of the ordinary can make it through: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17732753/293280

Comment: @DigitalCake For something simple like this I would do `raise unless WHITELISTED_NAMED_SCOPES.include?( params[:action] )`

Answer (score 10):

Although @kolrie has the correct answer, it is not safe at all.

It should be whitelisted as follows:

```
scope = ["first_scope", "second_scope", "default_scope"].include? params[:action] ? params[:scope] : "default_scope"
@case_studies = CaseStudy.send(scope)
```

Answer (score 1):

To have an extra layer of security on top of the whitelisting BookOfGreg suggested, use [public_send](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/public_send) instead of `send`, it'll only work calling methods of the public interface, while `send` can reach even private methods.

So:

`CaseStudy.public_send(:some_scope)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, that's what you should call it:

```
@case_studies = CaseStudy.send(:some_named_scope)
```

You can use send to call a method and pass either a symbol or a string to it.

Comment: I gave that a try but I maybe missing something. 
$ CaseStudy.const_get("work"),  
NameError: wrong constant name work  
were as CaseStudy.work is a valid scope.